# Why does Jupyter display of floating-point values differ from Python console?

Tags: python, floating-point, jupyter-notebook

When I run the following code in Jupyter 4.3.1 (Python 2.7.13)

```
import numpy as np
for i in np.arange(5, 6, 0.1):
    print(i)
```

I got the following output

```
5.0
5.1
5.199999999999999
5.299999999999999
5.399999999999999
5.499999999999998
5.599999999999998
5.6999999999999975
5.799999999999997
5.899999999999997
```

However, when I run the code in the console, I got the following output

```
5.0
5.1
5.2
5.3
5.4
5.5
5.6
5.7
5.8
5.9
```

Why does the Jupyter output differ from the console output?

Comment: `0.1` in code is not exactly 0.1

Comment: @ThierryLathuille, I've edited the question, for some reason the output is different in console and in jupyter

Comment: I don't know what 'console' you're using. In the REPL with Python 3.6, I get exactly what you get with Jupyter. Your console prints rounded values of your numbers.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille: The question specifies Python 2.7.13. When I try with 2.7.10, I get the output shown for the “console” output.

Comment: @com Please change `print` line to: `print type(i), str(i), repr(i)`, and show results for both environments.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille: I reopened this question because the problem it asks about is a difference between two pieces of software. It is not a question about how floating point works. Please do not promiscuously close questions as duplicates of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @roganjosh: I reopened this question because the problem it asks about is a difference between two pieces of software. It is not a question about how floating point works. Please do not promiscuously close questions as duplicates of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @PatrickArtner: I reopened this question because the problem it asks about is a difference between two pieces of software. It is not a question about how floating point works. Please do not promiscuously close questions as duplicates of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @MichalTurczyn: I reopened this question because the problem it asks about is a difference between two pieces of software. It is not a question about how floating point works. Please do not promiscuously close questions as duplicates of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet: I reopened this question because the problem it asks about is a difference between two pieces of software. It is not a question about how floating point works. Please do not promiscuously close questions as duplicates of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that you're using the same versions of Python and NumPy in both environments? What do `np.__version__` and `sys.version_info` show in both cases? I suspect that your Jupyter session is actually using Python 3.